# Limitation in parse of JSON with Python3.x. How to get around restrictions

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I parse json table with python 3.8

```
    url = 'https://api.gbif.org/v1/occurrence/search/'
    key={'limit':10}
    response = requests.get(url,params=key)
    df=response.json()
    df
```

its structure of json file and it have `'limit': ,` parameter which cannot be more 300 and show only first 300 objects of `'results':`.
How i can see other objects.
Thanks

```
    {'offset': 0,
    'limit': 10,
    'endOfRecords': False,
    'count': 1643179592,
    'results': [{'var1': ccc,
      'var2:'aaa'},
      {'var1':'aaa',
      'var2':'bbb',
      'var3:'ccc'}]
     }
```

Comment: So, to confirm, you're saying that this api returns a maximum of 300 search results, and you want to know how to retrieve more?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely true.

Comment: Have you tried looking in your devtools network tab and inspecting the requests your browser makes when viewing the page normally? That's probably the best place to start